# Show Bootstrap modal on hover button

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I created a modal using the bootstrap. Is there a way to open the modal that I do hover over the button?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5sikx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**code**

Open modal

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `mouseenter` attribute directive like this:

```
(mouseenter)="$event.target.click()"
```

```
<button (mouseenter)="$event.target.click()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>
```

---

Another way:

```
<button (mouseenter)="onMouseEnter($event)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>
```

In your controller:

```
onMouseEnter(event: any): void {
    event.target.click();
}
```

---

You can read the **mouseenter** documentation rigth here:
https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: Perfect! is it possible to close the modal when I remove the mouse from the button?